# Data Too Long For Column '_LoginPass' at Row 1 C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

Good day, I have this error when I'm trying to insert my encrypted data to my Database

[image]

Now here's my script for `Encryption`

```
    public void Encrypt(TextBox txtEncrypt, string hash, byte[] results)
    {
        hash = "placeholder";
        byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtEncrypt.Text);
        using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
            {
                ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();
                results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                txtEncrypt.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
                //MessageBox.Show("Encryption :" + Convert.ToBase64String(results,0,results.Length));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am implementing it on another class like this

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Best practice in c# to interact with database (using statement)
            using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connection.connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                //Add the stored procedure that we uses in the mysqlworkbench
                MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("LoginAdd", mysqlCon);
                mysqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //Use trim to avoid spaces

                method.Encrypt(textBox2,hash,results);

                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginID", LoginID);
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginUser", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginPass", textBox2);
                mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Registered Succesfully");
                //proceed to login page
                this.Hide();
                method.ConstantLoginForm();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+ ex);
        }
    }
```

I already search some data's and I found this.

[image]

I tried doing it but nothing happens

Comment: What is the column type of `_LoginPass`?

Comment: @stdunbar its a Varchar(45)

Comment: @stdunbar tried a higher value but didn't do.

Comment: This still appears to be the size of the field for storing the password. What is the length of  text in TextBox2

Comment: @CharlesMay You mean MaxLength ? its 32767

Comment: No, the length of its contents at the moment you try to pass it to the parameter for storing into the database.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("" + textBox2.TextLength);` = 12 @CharlesMay

Comment: OK, try passing `textBox2.Text` to the parameter value. You've left of the `.Text` part and are trying to pass in the object.

Comment: F**k . That was so idiot of me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Charles May said I've left of the `.Text` part and are trying to pass in the object.

So I just need to change this part

```
 mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginPass", textBox2);
```

to this some like this code

```
 mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginPass", textBox2.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your _LoginPass column size to varchar(50) or more.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: The error is in this line mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginPass", textBox2); you need to write textBox2.Text